# Kafka KSQL equivale of VIEW for consumer that need a subset of data

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

We are implementing an ETL in Kafka to load data from a single source into different target system with different consumer.
Every consumer needs a subset of the data and for this we have the following topics:

topicA ---> infinite retention store all the data from the source

topicB --> finite retention populated by a KSQL statement with a where clause

Example:

```
CREATE STREAM streamA WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topicA')

CREATE STREAM streamB WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topicB') AS SELECT * FROM streamA WHERE gender='MALE'
```

After that we have a sink connector or a consumer connected to topicB to consume only data which gender is male or with some columns name remapped

Since we are running an initial import of an important amount of data I would like to understand if there is any way to reduce the amount of storage required for the streamB since its data is just a replica of topicA.
In SQL I would implement it a VIEW, how can I do that in KSQL?

My ideas is to have a lower retention period for topicB but this doesn't solve issue with the initial load (e.g if I have to load 10TB of data at the beginning even if I have 1 day retention period for one day I would need 10TB + 5TB). Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I see the following options if you want to minimise the space that topicB takes up in your cluster:

1. Reduce your time based retention setting for the topic, e.g. to 6 hours, or 1 hour, or 30 minutes, etc.
2. Use a size based retention setting for the topic, e.g. 100MB per partition.

However, note, in each case it will be up to you to ensure your consumer is capable of consuming the data before the retention policy kicks in and deletes the data.   If data is deleted before the consumer can consume it, the consumer will log a warning.

3. Reduce the replication factor of the topic.  You're hopefully running with a replication factor of at least 3 for your main 'golden truth' topic, so that its resilient to machine failures.  But you may be able to run with a lower factor for topic b, e.g. 2, or 1.  This would halve / third the storage cost.  Of course, if you lost a machine/disk during the process and you only had 1 replica, you'd lose data and need to recover from this.
4. Expand your Kafka cluster!